# open new window after cancel confirmation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, confirm

I want, when the user clicks on closing the web page window/tab, a cancel confirmation should come up and when the user clicks "OK", the current page closes and a new window is opened.

This is what I've done so far but it doesn't work:

```
function confirmit(){
    var closeit= confirm("شكراً لك :) فقط نرجوا القليل من وقتك لتعبئة الاستبانة");
    if (closeit == true){
        window.open("https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/3DMJGYX", "الاستبانة");} 
    else{
        window.close();}}
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://gadgetron.store/chatbot/run_python_clear_chatM/',});
    confirmit();
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's a formatting issue or not, but on the line where you declare your `closeit` variable, it looks like there are no opening quotes for the `confirm` statement but rather two sets of closing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple of punctuation errors.  I'm not sure exactly what the text in your `confirm` statement is, so I can't say exactly where the quotes should go, but this is what you need to change:

- In your `var closeit` declaration, you have two sets of closing double quotes -- `")");` -- but no opening quotes.  You'll need to add the opening quotes, and also change one set of the double quotes to single quotes (`' '`).
- Where you assign the `url` value in the `$.ajax()` method, you have a comma after the URL without a second parameter.  That comma should be removed.